# Google Analytics custom fields

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I'm tring to add custom fields on google analytics script to track facebook ads/posts.
I read that i have to add some custom fields on analytics script:

```
_gaq.push(['setCampSourceKey', 'utm_source']);
_gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', 'utm_medium']);
....etc.
```

the problem is that i see that google changed the analytics traking code format like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'XXXXX.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Any ideas how should i add this custom fields? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for GA Universal is...

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', '<name>');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', '<name>');
```

Check out [this reference page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trafficsources) for all the fields.